# How to find the closing price of a historical candle whose bar_index is known

Tags: pine-script

I would like to find the closing price of a historical candle whose `bar_index`  value is known (for example: 4530). I have no other information about this candle. How could I find the closing price of this candle?

I tried to use `ta.valuewhen(condition=bar_index == 4530, source=close, occurrence=0)`, but I get `NaN`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [history reference operator](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Operators.html#history-reference-operator) for this.

If `target` is your target `bar_index` (4530), it is `bar_index - target` bars away from the current bar.

So, something like this should do:

```
target_idx = 4530
target_idx_diff = bar_index - target_idx
is_target_idx_valid = bar_index >= target_idx

float close_at_target_idx = is_target_idx_valid ? close[target_idx_diff] : na
```